# Query and its total row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table generated by a query with data drawn from another sheet. At the end of of the table, I am adding a total-row.

When the rows generated by the query is more, total-row restricts the table. Is there any way to detect the number of rows generated by the query and insert more rows above the total-row?

I have the number of rows generated by the query displayed in a cell and row number of total-row in another cell. Can a macro be triggered when the first is more than the second?

Regards,
Pravin Kumar.

It is not possible to append the total row, since it depends on the query result and it will generate a redundancy problem. Any solution to that?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

add it into your query in array `{}`. lets say your QUERY outputs 3 columns and 3rd column holds the sum:

```
={QUERY(A:C, "select A,B,sum(C) where A = 'xx' group by A,B label sum(C)''", 0); 
 "Total", "", QUERY(A:C, "select sum(C) where A = 'xx' label sum(C)''")}
```

[image]

or to add row between:

[image]